# Saving credentials in my app with Firebase UI

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using Firebase UI, it is working fine.
When I open the app I give one phone number and I sign in, but when I close and again open the app again give me a code.

I want that when I close the app and again open it doesn't give me again the code.

I know then this make with one if but I don't know how to make the best.

I was using firebase UI, I did see something about smart lock password of google but I don't know if this is right because the storage should be local

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.xx.xx.R;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText et_login, et_password;
    Button bt_login, bt_register;
    private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        et_login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_login);
        et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);

        bt_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_login);
        bt_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_register);

        bt_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        bt_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Choose authentication providers
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build());

        // Create and launch sign-in intent
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Successfully signed in
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                //Save user to local database
                // ...
            } else {
                // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
                // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
                // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The app should give me one number and save it, then when I close the app and open again it will not give me access again if not log in with before credential stored in the app.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is that in `onStart` check if the user is signed in or not, if the user is signed in then navigate to your `MainActivity` or any other Activity -

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if the user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    // do your stuff
            if (currentUser != null) {
                // go to MainActivity
            } else {
                // user doesn't exist
            }

}
```